# How to find the feature/(data column) that separates each cluster of K-means?

Tags: k-means

I have a general question on applying k-means clustering on the datasets..

How to find the feature/(data column) that separates each cluster of K-means?

may be using scikit-learn  in python ..

Best Regards,
Swati

Comment: do you mean predicted labels or cluster centers? You can get both of them using `kmeans.labels_` and `kmeans.cluster_centers_`.  Check documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Not exactly.. I mean the actual input columns (independent variables).. How to find which columns are different in each of the cluster